# How to include PDF image in Latex

Tags: graphics, pdf

I want to use a PDF image embedded as a figure. I am using the following code. The result is a blank page followed by a page without any figure at all. Just the text appears on the second page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
   \includepdf[width=0.4\textwidth, angle = 0]{image1.pdf}
   Here goes the text
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includegraphics`, not `\includepdf`. You need the `graphicx` package, however!

Comment: that or just graphicx package and `\includegraphics{image1}` should be enough to include a one page pdf.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is a duplicate, surely?

Comment: I dont want to include full PDF Page....instead I need only the image.
In case if has to be a page, then I need to define the bounding limits for PDF to fit within.

Presently upon using {\includegraphics} I am getting following error.

! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in image1.pdf (no BoundingBox).

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you are using pdfTeX (which is included with MiKTeX), just use the `graphicx` package, [and `\includegraphics`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, angle=0]{image1.pdf}
   Here goes the text
\end{document}
```

---

Looking into the comments, the question appears to ask how to clip part of a PDF image. This can be done with `trim={<left> <lower> <right> <upper>}` and `clip` options:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, trim={0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 11.3cm}, clip]{image1.pdf}
```

Comment: P.S. I am using MikTex

Comment: @RehanJamshed: MikTeX is a distribution that contains `pdflatex` ;-)

Comment: MikTeX is not what you are using to compile. MikTeX is just a TeX distro, that is a way to fetch latex packages and binaries on the CTAN repository and to install them on your computer. pdfTeX is probably what your are using to compile when launching a latex command. It might be xetex, but Mike T's answer also matches.

Comment: @RehanJamshed See http://seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html

Answer (score 3):

```
\includegraphics[page=1, trim = 18mm 100mm 18mm 5mm, clip, width=14.35cm]{file.pdf}
```

Here you can decide pagenumber, trim is the bounding box and you have to clip. This should work.

EDIT:
After further investigation I can conform.
You are calling latex .tex

But as the documentation of pdfpages you can see, that calling latex in dvi mode it will only include a pdf dummy, so you cannot see any image in this way.

You have two options:

Option 1: You can convert your pdf image to an eps file, so latex can handle this.
Option 2: You call your file via pdflatex and all will be fine, /maybe you have to replace your command and use includegraphics instead.

calling latex and include pdf images seems to be impossible.

I am sure that you call latex instead of pdflatex, in this case I am able to reproduce this error.

Comment: Note to OP: all options are *optional*; you do not need `page`, `trim`, `clip`, or `width` to make this work. Also, Peter: you should avoid using absolute lengths for `width` :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred you are alright. But I thought, that I can handle the error of OP  LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in image1.pdf in this way.

Comment: Thanks @PeterEbelsberger but I am still getting the error as follows:

Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command which
(pdfpages)                will insert empty pages instead of the actual PDF,
(pdfpages)                because we are running in DVI mode or with
(pdfpages)                dvips driver.

))) (C:\Work\Latex\PDF_Image.aux)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\pdflscape.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\lscape.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"))

! Package keyval Error: page undefined.