# How to avoid pagebreak before \includepdf and add caption (figure)?

Tags: pdfpages

I have created a figure saved as a pdf and would like to include it in my document. When I use the following commands there is a pagebreak between my figure and the text pieces above and below. Also I don't know how to include a figure caption to my pdf. This is what I use:

```
\includepdf[scale=0.85, angle=90, pagecommand={}]{Assembly_process.pdf}
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Does this question maybe help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287140/how-to-include-pdf-image-in-latex/287143 I think you might not need to use includepdf

Comment: @nhck i need the figure in high resolution. Therefore i am using pdf

Comment: Use `\includegraphics[scale=0.85, angle=90]{Assembly_process.pdf}`. That will work fine. `\includepdf` is for whole pages.

Comment: It was from pdfpages source code that I discovered the [page=...] option of \includegraphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to tex.se! The package `graphicx` can also load pdfs. (In the following the `example-image`s are actually pdfs.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Text \includegraphics[scale=0.4,angle=90]{example-image-a.pdf} \bigskip

With caption:

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4,angle=90]{example-image-b.pdf}
    \caption{This is the caption for b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help and fast response. I will use this forum for future questions for sure. @TivV